# How to know which Python is running in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use Jupyter notebook in a browser for Python programming, I have installed Anaconda (Python 3.5). But I'm quite sure that Jupyter is running my python commands with the native python interpreter and not with anaconda. How can I change it and use Anaconda as interpreter?

Comment: You could find the kernel settings for the Jupyter configuration and modify the python executable

Comment: I had this problem, and for the second part of your problem I solved it by reinstalling jupyter using conda: ```conda install jupyter```.

Answer (score 385):

```
from platform import python_version

print(python_version())
```

This will give you the exact version of python running your script. eg output:

```
3.6.5
```

Comment: this should be selected as the answer to the posted question.

Comment: The OP is asking to find which executable is running (system/anaconda), not which version. The answer by P. Camilleri is the solution

Comment: Answer fails to answer the question. Answer fails to succinctly print the version (and related metadata) of the active Python interpreter with a terse one-liner like `from sys import version; version`. Naturally, 240 upvotes ensue. Makes sense. As @MrMartin suggests, **see literally any other answer than this.**

Comment: this works: from platform import python_version

print(python_version())

Comment: This tells you the version, but how does it tell you the *path* of the python executable that's currently running?  That seems to be more what OP is about (and what I was looking for when searching led me to this page).

Answer (score 108):

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

will give you the interpreter. You can select the interpreter you want when you create a new notebook. Make sure the path to your anaconda interpreter is added to your path (somewhere in your bashrc/bash_profile most likely).

For example I used to have the following line in my .bash_profile, that I added manually :

```
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned in a comment, this is not the proper way to add anaconda to the path. Quoting Anaconda's doc, this should be done instead after install, using `conda init`:

> *Should I add Anaconda to the macOS or Linux PATH?*
>
> We do not recommend adding Anaconda to the PATH manually. During
>   installation, you will be asked “Do you wish the installer to
>   initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?” We recommend “yes”. If
>   you enter “no”, then conda will not modify your shell scripts at all.
>   In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first
>   run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` and then run `conda init`

Comment: I'm running this in Spyder and no results but Jupyter is ok. I wonder why?

Comment: The Conda docs recommend against adding to the PATH like that.

Comment: @AMC you're right, thank you. I have edited to point towards  `conda init`

Comment: Running `sys.executable`  returns `'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'` - not very useful.  We already know that it's Python (from the heading of the OP) and what we want to know is the version of Python being used.  Thank you.

Comment: @Confounded you may have different intepreters on your machine with different versions. The OP is asking which interpreter is called, not which version.

Answer (score 89):

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
```

Seen below :- output when i run JupyterNotebook outside a CONDA venv

```
/home/dhankar/anaconda2/bin/python
2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Seen below when i run same JupyterNoteBook within a CONDA Venv created with command --

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 ## Here - py35 , is name of my VENV
```

in my Jupyter Notebook it prints :-

```
/home/dhankar/anaconda2/envs/py35/bin/python
3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

also if you already have various VENV's created with different versions of Python you switch to the desired Kernel by choosing KERNEL >> CHANGE KERNEL from within the JupyterNotebook menu...
[JupyterNotebookScreencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoMEE.png)

Also to install ipykernel within an existing CONDA Virtual Environment -

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments

#### Source --- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1524

```
 $ /path/to/python -m  ipykernel install --help
 usage: ipython-kernel-install [-h] [--user] [--name NAME]
                          [--display-name DISPLAY_NAME]
                          [--profile PROFILE] [--prefix PREFIX]
                          [--sys-prefix]
```

Install the IPython kernel spec.

optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
--user                Install for the current user instead of system-wide
--name NAME           Specify a name for the kernelspec. This is needed to
have multiple IPython kernels at the same time.
--display-name DISPLAY_NAME
Specify the display name for the kernelspec. This is
helpful when you have multiple IPython kernels.
--profile PROFILE     Specify an IPython profile to load. This can be used
to create custom versions of the kernel.
--prefix PREFIX       Specify an install prefix for the kernelspec. This is
needed to install into a non-default location, such as
a conda/virtual-env.
--sys-prefix          Install to Python's sys.prefix. Shorthand for
--prefix='/Users/bussonniermatthias/anaconda'. For use
in conda/virtual-envs.

Answer (score 23):

### You can check python version using

```
!python -V
```

or

```
!python --version
```

`Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

---

#### You can add Conda environment to your jupyter notebook

**Step 1:** Create a Conda environment.

```
conda create --name firstEnv
```

**Step 2:** Activate the environment using the command as shown in the console.

```
conda activate firstEnv

conda install -c conda-forge <package-name>
```

E.g.

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

**Step 3:** set this conda environment on your jupyter notebook

```
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=firstEnv
```

**Step 4:** Just check your Jupyter Notebook, to see firstEnv

---

You can refer this article

https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084

Comment: This returns the main interpreter in the environment, however, if Jupyter is using a different one the wrong version is returned. E.g. If the Jupyter kernel is using 3.10 but 3.11 is also installed and callable through the "python" command (as main), 3.11 will be returned.

Answer (score 8):

**Looking the Python version**

Jupyter menu help/about will show the Python version

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the wrong backend system you can change the backend `kernel` by creating a new or editing the existing `kernel.json` in the `kernels` folder of your jupyter data path `jupyter --paths`. You can have multiple kernels (R, Python2, Python3 (+virtualenvs), Haskell), e.g. you can create an `Anaconda` specific kernel:

```
$ <anaconda-path>/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name anaconda --display-name "Anaconda"
```

Should create a new kernel:

`<jupyter-data-dir>/kernels/anaconda/kernel.json`

```
{
    "argv": [ "<anaconda-path>/bin/python3", "-m", "ipykernel", "-f", "{connection_file}" ],
    "display_name": "Anaconda",
    "language": "python"
}
```

You need to ensure `ipykernel` package is installed in the anaconda distribution.

This way you can just switch between kernels and have different notebooks using different kernels.

Comment: To add more kernelspecs, see also the [IPython kernel install docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Check the Python Version**

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Creating a virtual environment for Jupyter Notebooks**

A minimal Python install is

```
sudo apt install python3.7 python3.7-venv python3.7-minimal python3.7-distutils python3.7-dev python3.7-gdbm python3-gdbm-dbg python3-pip
```

Then you can create and use the environment

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 -m venv test
cd test
source test/bin/activate
pip install jupyter matplotlib seaborn numpy pandas scipy
# install other packages you need with pip/apt
jupyter notebook
deactivate
```

You can make a kernel for Jupyter with

```
ipython3 kernel install --user --name=test
```