# Is there a way to tell which kernel a jupyter notebook was built with?

Tags: python, julia, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have multiple kernels installed in Jupyter.  without fully starting Jupyter in a browser I'd like to know which version of Python or Julia or R was used to create the notebook.  is there a way to query the ipynb file using command line?

[How to know which is running in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694528/how-to-know-which-is-running-in-jupyter-notebook)
discusses how to change kernels.  I'd like to be able just to interrogate the notebook.

Comment: Jupyter Notebook file is a JSON document. It has metadata in there containing all information you need. You could parse it using `jq` or write your own Python script using `json` library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Georgy said, you can use `jq`, ie.:

```
ismael-vc@toybox ~/Downloads % cat Untitled.ipynb | jq '.metadata.kernelspec'
{
  "display_name": "Julia 0.6.0",
  "language": "julia",
  "name": "julia-0.6"
}
```