# PySpark worker cannot import packages while they are installed

Tags: import, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, python-module, google-cloud-dataproc

I've recently set up a cluster(1 master & 2 slaves) on gcloud DataProc. 
I have managed to have a jupyter notebook interface with a PySpark kernel.
Everything works as long as my workers do not have to execute code that needs foreign packages such as NumPy or sklearn. For example, I get this error :

```
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

[a bit of the huge error log when I try to use pairwise_distance from sklearn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4XN3.jpg)

When I ssh on the workers and type

```
python
>>> help('modules')
```

I can see that all the packages are properly installed so it is not the problem.

When I type `which python` I get a path let's say `/opt/conda/bin/python`
And when I check the PYSPARK_PYTHON with `echo $PYSPARK_PYTHON` I get the same path. From this we can deduce that spark uses the "good" version of python which has all the packages installed. So it is not the problem.

I don't understand why my workers are not able to use packages since they are properly installed and PATHs variables seem fine.

Any clues ?
I am a bit lost and hopeless so I might be omiting information, don't hesitate to ask.

For those wondering, I followed this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/02/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-jupyter-notebooks-with-apache-spark-on-google-cloud) until step 4 to set up my environment PySpark on gcloud.

Comment: Did you run `!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn` from the notebook before importing it? Did you make sure you are using the right interpreter [from the notebook too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694528/how-to-know-which-is-running-in-jupyter-notebook)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to fix it.

The main "issue" so to say was that I was connected as an user on my cluster and that I lacked so priviledges especially is the `/opt/conda/` directory.

Therefore when I used `pip` or `conda` to install packages it failed.

I tried to used `pip` with the `--user` option, it installed stuff but not where I wanted.

At this point, I was fustrated because I could not install packages like everybody was telling me to do using `pip` and `conda` but as mentionned on the original post it looked like they were already properly installed.

Since priviledges prevented me to use `pip` and `conda` efficiently and since this is a virtual machine in the cloud somewhere, I decided to change the ownershp of the `/opt/conda/` directory with `sudo chown`.

Being owner of `/opt/conda/` permitted me too install all the packages with `conda` and it worked after. My PySpark Notebook was running just fine.

I do not recommend this solution to users facing this problem on their own private machine but my problem was on a virtual machine in the Google cloud used only for PySpark so the risk that changing ownership will come back at me one day is pretty low.

If somebody has a better and **cleaner** solution, fell free to post it here.