# How to change Jupyter's python version from 3.7 to 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have python 3.7.0 and 3.8.2 installed in my computer, and my jupyter uses the 3.7 version.
I want Jupyter to use version 3.8 instead, but after searching through here I only found how to change from version 2.x to 3.x.

Is there a way to do this? Jupyter was installed with pip.

If this helps, I only needed to install 3.7 for a specific project - but I don't use it anymore - so I'm willing to uninstall it if it makes things easier.

Comment: How did you install Jupyter? I think there are a few different ways it's commonly installed, and knowing how might help us figure out

Comment: Why don't you make a virtual env nd launch jupyter from there. Or you could make a `conda` environment and launch from there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46902466/1275942 has some useful commands; can you share their output?

Comment: @Keon I installed Jupyter with pip

Comment: Can you share the results from opening a jupyter notebook and running "import sys;
 print(sys.executable); print(sys.version); print(sys.version_info)" (sorry comments are mangling the formatting)?

Comment: This is what I got @Keon: https://pastebin.com/Kcwkjp7f

Comment: Any luck with this? Having the same issue.