# Cannot read file with PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm trying to upload example from dash documentation.
When I try (with PyCharm)

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv'
)
```

I get these errors.
But when I try the same code with Anaconda Jupyter it works fine. It means problem is not in my OS but in PyCharm.
Can you advise what should I do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1342, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 933, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1217, in _make_engine
    self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 670, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 339, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
  File "/Users/zaurguliyev/Documents/PyTraining/PyCharm/test/sales_analysis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 239, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1385, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1345, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You've cut off the actual useful error message, and it's generally better to provide a cut-and-paste of the error text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Please include the _whole_ error message as text in your question; images aren't searchable, can't be copy and pasted and are not accessible for those who have trouble seeing.

Comment: sorry, it looked all the same. added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check whether you're using the same Python interpreter and Pandas version in both Jupyter and PyCharm.

Find Jupyter interpreter: [How to know which Python is running in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694528/how-to-know-which-python-is-running-in-jupyter-notebook)
(Check this if using Spyder: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment)

Check if it's the same in PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter